# Angular Module Dependency and controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, dependencies

I'm still learning angularjs, trying different free online tutorials, i made below app, but not sure why it's not working, i think it's the dependency, can anyone give me bit explanations please.

my knowledge is super limited

```
<div ng-app="app">
    <span odometer="'200'">
    <span odometer="visitors">
    <span odometer="visitors" odometer-options="{theme: 'digital', duration: 3000}">

    <div ng-controller="MyAngularishCtrl">
      Random number : {{AngularishRNGesus}}
    </div>

</div>
```

below is my js file

```
var myApp = angular.module('app', ['ui.odometer']);

app.controller('MyAngularishCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {

$scope.AngularishRNGesus = 0;
function update() {
    $scope.AngularishRNGesus = Math.round((Math.random() * 10) * 10);
}
$interval(update, 1000 * 2);
});
```

if i remove dependency 'ui.odometer', then controller works, but if have it, then controller won't work, i m confused... help please
please.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/JxT2bQltOXwBuexO8Zew

Answer (score 0):

its a dependency that needs to be present in javascript .... can you ensure that the javascript code for it is available ... plunkr will help a lot ....

It is failing because either it is not able to find javascript for 'ui.odometer'
or it is incorrect

Comment: I downloaded odometer.js file, and attached, if I remove dependency, and leave it like var myApp = angular.module('app', []); then the controller works, if I have ui.odometer, then controller won't work the custom directive works... strange

Comment: please see order of attaching .... code for odometer.js should be before your application code ... please put in plunkr so that community members can work and resolve it ....

Comment: buddy the way you have included the script for odometer files is incorrect ... kindly go to network and see what is getting downloaded ... its not the library ... it is its page ... rectifiy it and it will work .. compare it with the library of angular that gets downloaded ...